# Dask scheduler limit (fps)

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

On https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/actors.html#motivation I read `the scheduler can coordinate about 4000 tasks per second`.
Is this really the upper limit of the scheduler, or can it be increased somehow?
I'm asking for a use case where I have a Dask distributed computing graph, processing image data. Images are processed frame by frame, so I assume every frame counts as (at least) 1 task?

So can I deduct that the upper limit of a Dask cluster is 4000 frames per second?

Thanks for any help/info/workaround!

Answer (score 0):

> Is this really the upper limit of the scheduler

Today, yes.

> so I assume every frame counts as (at least) 1 task?

Not necessarily, you can organize things in many ways.  Most Dask collections like Dask array, Dask dataframe, and Dask bag, will automatically batch things for you.

See https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/best-practices.html#avoid-very-large-graphs